# Split view-like UI in OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, uisplitviewcontroller

I've developed quite a few apps for iOS and am giving OSX apps a go. What would be the best approach to designing a UI like the split view on iPad apps? For a mac-based example, think of how the playlists work in iTunes. You select an option on the left, and a table view selects a different set of data based on what you selected.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sort of interface is known as a [source list](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AppleHIGuidelines/Windows/Windows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000961-CHDDIGDE) or source view. It's actually a special style applied to an outline view. Apple provides the [SourceView sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SourceView/Introduction/Intro.html) which illustrates the technique.